# Underlying Sample Space in Continuous Market Model

Tags: stochastic-processes

E.g., a model for $N$ stocks might have each follow a GBM $dS_i = \mu_i S_i dt + \sigma_i S_i dW_i$, where each $W_i$ is independent of the others.  Letting $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be the underlying probability space, what should I be thinking of for $\Omega$?

Perhaps it's easier with just one stochastic process?  Some candidate spaces I've heard of are $\Omega = \{$infinite sequences of coin tosses$\}$ and $\Omega = \{$continuous functions on $[0,T]$ starting at $0\}$, but I can't really get a good handle on these.  Is there a a good explanation for these, or a better example of the possible underlying space?  I would prefer a rigorous (measure-theoretic) explanation, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the following:

- the tripple $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is an abstract probability space with all the properties that I assume that you know.
- then we can define random variables as mappings from this probability space to the real numbers
  $$
  X: \omega \mapsto X(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}.
  $$
  But we want to study processes
  $$
  (X_t)_{t \ge 0}: \omega \mapsto (X_t(\omega))_{t \ge 0} \in W,
  $$
  where the canonical space, $W$, for these continuous (no jumps) stochastic processes is [Wiener space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Wiener_space) - the space of continuous functions on the real (half-) line.

If you search the internet for these keywords (Wiener space, stochastic process) then you find the mathematical details. You can start e.g. [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m280_09/ch5.pdf).

Comment: thanks for the response.  I've asked an unrelated question regarding that note set you linked about joint probabilities I've been confused about lately.  I wouldn't mind hearing your thoughts: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18588/joint-probability-distribution-only-measures-product-sets